# The problem with the input function in jupiter

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to concatenate, but nothing works for some reason jupyter reduces all variables to 'PyodideFuture' and does not want to work with them[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Kxr.png)

I tried to set input() in different ways, but it did not lead me to success

Comment: Did you overwrite the  built-in `input` function? Restart the kernel and just run that cell.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/problem-with-jupyter-online-version/17612)

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting the kernel with the 'Restart kernel' function. Changed browsers and even machines. It seems to me that I'm doing something wrong, I enter this code into the cell and press the 'SHIFT + ENTER' key combination, right? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed the kernel and everything worked normally!